# Web-Scraping Max Retries Rejected

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-headers, python-requests, screen-scraping

I have issues scraping certain websites, while others work. For example, this works:

```
page = requests.get('https://wsj.com/', proxies=proxydict)
```

But this doesn't:

```
page = requests.get('https://www.privateequityinternational.com/', proxies=proxydict)
```

I get a "max retries" error, even though I only scrape 1 page (and haven't scraped it before).

I've tried using a header for the websites that won't scrape but it hasn't worked. Is there a specific header I should use? How do I scrape that second website I've shown above ([www.privateequityinternational.com](http://www.privateequityinternational.com))? Thank you.

Comment: Use a headers parameter in get request ``headers={your header dict}``. In my case ``page = requests.get('https://www.privateequityinternational.com/')``  this is working

Comment: I get an ssl error from the first url `SSLError: hostname 'wsj.co m' doesn't match either of  ....`, I also get a warning from google in my browser, what is the site?

Comment: wsj.com is the Wall Street Journal @Padraic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the page is served over *http* in your browser not *https*, you get a warning from google when you try to access the page using https:

```
In [1]: import requests
   ...: page = requests.get('http://www.wsj.com')
   ...: 

In [2]: page
Out[2]: <Response [200]>
```